# memcpy instead of copy_to_user

Tags: c, linux-kernel

Let consider following code. For someone who read Linux Device Driver the context will be clear.

In short, 
sbull is a driver which acts a disk device and the sbull_transfer function aims to transfer block of data from/to disk/user_space.

And everything is clear expect one thing.
I don't understand why we can just simply use memcpy function. After all, we copy from user space so why it is possible? Usually, I noticed, that we should use copy_from_user()/copy_to_user().

I don't understand why we needn't to use them. Please explain.

```
static void sbull_transfer(struct sbull_dev *dev, unsigned long sector,
        unsigned long nsect, char *buffer, int write)
{
    unsigned long offset = sector*KERNEL_SECTOR_SIZE;
    unsigned long nbytes = nsect*KERNEL_SECTOR_SIZE;

    if ((offset + nbytes) > dev->size) {
        printk (KERN_NOTICE "Beyond-end write (%ld %ld)\n", offset, nbytes);
        return;
    }
    if (write)
        memcpy(dev->data + offset, buffer, nbytes);
    else
        memcpy(buffer, dev->data + offset, nbytes);
}
```

Comment: Are you sure that you can call this function from user space, passing a user space allocated buffer?

Comment: Have you registered `sbull_transfer()` as the read file operation when registering the device with fops?

Comment: @Jens Gustedt the question you reference is about the rationale behind the copy_to/from_user - this question here is about why copy_to/from_user hasn't been used - it is totally different

Comment: @tinky_winky I think Jens is correct.  This is the same question and I think the accepted answer is the answer to this question at all.

Comment: @JeremyP I can't agree with that. In my opinion it is clear that OP is thinking that copy_from/to_user has been omitted. He doesn't ask why copy_to_user exist as he probably knows this (or thinks that he knows). The reference question is about "Why is that we should use copy_to_user instead of memcpy()". It is totally different. OP knows why we should and he asks why we don't.

Comment: @tinky_winky On reflection, I think you are correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sbull driver can implement the actual data transfer with a simple memcpy call because data is already in memory, after all.

Function

```
static void sbull_request(request_queue_t *q)
{
    struct request *req;

    while ((req = elv_next_request(q)) != NULL) {
        struct sbull_dev *dev = req->rq_disk->private_data;
        if (! blk_fs_request(req)) {
            printk (KERN_NOTICE "Skip non-fs request\n");
            end_request(req, 0);
            continue;
        }
        sbull_transfer(dev, req->sector, req->current_nr_sectors,
                req->buffer, rq_data_dir(req));
        end_request(req, 1);
    }
}
```

calls `elv_next_request` before data is passed to `sbull_transfer`. Request function takes care about copying data to/from user space. The *buffer* contained in returned `request` struct is described in book as:

> char *buffer;
>
> A pointer to the buffer to or from which the data should
> be transferred. **This pointer is a kernel virtual address** and can be
> dereferenced directly by the driver if need be.

Comment: Could you elaborate your answer, please?

Comment: you are welcome, tinky-winky is very glad that helped